# Reading time base registers in PowerPC 440 from c code

Tags: c, assembly, cpu-registers, powerpc

I'm currently working with a PowerPC 440 embedded processor. I'm trying to read the upper and lower time base registers (TBU and TBL) using some in-line assembly code but the values I get don't change. According to the documentation, the time base "is a 64-bit register which increments once during each period of the source clock, and provides a time reference". It sounds like I should be able to read the contents of these registers using the mfspr instruction.

I've tried it using the following code:

```
uint32_t tbuval = 0, tblval = 0;
__asm__ volatile("mfspr %0, %[regnum]" : "=r"(tblval) : [regnum]"r"(0x10C));
__asm__ volatile("mfspr %0, %[regnum]" : "=r"(tbuval) : [regnum]"r"(0x10D));

printf("TBU: %d, TBL: %d\n", tbuval, tblval);
```

If I put this in a loop, I just keep getting identical values for each one. In the datasheet for the processor, the core clock frequency is listed as 100 MHz. If I read the TBU and TBL registers every 1 second, shouldn't they be increasing by about 100 million each time I read them, or is there some part of this that I'm missing?

thanks,
Melissa

In the documentation, the memory mapped register GPT0_TBC is also discussed, and I tried to read that using the "lwz" instruction but could not make that work either.

Comment: First step might be to disassemble your code and see if it is actually generating the `mfspr` instructions you expect.

Comment: That looks like correct inline asm syntax to me, including `volatile` which prevents the compiler from hoisting it out of the loop and using the same value repeatedly.  Is there maybe a bit in a control register that controls whether the time-base increments or not?  I assume `mfspr` is Move From SPecial Register?  If those are the correct `regnum` constants, it should be reading upper/lower halves of the time.  When you say you get the same value every time, is it `0`?

Comment: @PeterCordes Do the variables `tbuval` and `tblval` also need to be volatile?

Comment: @pmacfarlane: No.  Those are just plain local variables that the compiler knows are written by the black-box asm statement and read by `printf`.  So they don't need to be `volatile` for the same reason `int now = time(NULL)` or `clock_t now = clock()` don't need to be `volatile`.  The `"=r"(tblval)` means essentially the same thing to the compiler as `tblval = unknown_function(0x10C);`, in terms of how it handles the "return value".  (Not in terms of the function maybe having side-effects or its calling convention; if it did you'd have to describe those to the compiler.)

Comment: @PeterCordes the values I get are non-zero, but the same for both tbl and tbu and the same for each iteration of the loop. That's a good idea about a control bit, I'll look in the docs and see.